# increment all C++ std::vector values by a constant value

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to increment all the elements of an `std::vector<int>` with a constant `int` value.

In other words, if I have a vector with elements: `1 2 3 4 5`

I want to do something like

```
vect += 5;
```

So the elements will be: `6 7 8 9 10`.

I tried to overload `operator +=` but it turns out I don't know how to do it :S I tried this:

```
std::vector<int> & operator += (const int & increment) {
    for (int &i : *this)
        *this[i] = *this[i] + increment;
}
```

And this compiles, but whenever I use it I get this error:

```
no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<int>’ and ‘int’)
 vec += 3;
        ^
```

Any advice? I would like to do it this way instead of a regular `increment(vector, value)` function.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to keep on using `std::vector`, the C++ standard library have many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). For this the best would probably be [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: Or `std::for_each`. In practice, though, if the questioner doesn't want to copy and paste the range-based for loop that they have already written, then they probably won't want to copy and paste a call to an algorithm either. I think the question is about *reducing* boilerplate, perhaps beyond what C++ comfortably supports :-)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Also `std::transform` is not necessarily linear and may perform better than custom linear `for` loop or `std::for_each`.

Comment: I want to mark Joachim's answer as valid since it looks more stylish than std::valarray in terms of compatibility with vectors. However I cannot vote due to reputation. Thank you @JoachimPileborg and all the others for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned before, don't try to add new functions to `std::vector`, you are not allowed to.
The standard says you can only open the `std::` namespace to specialize **existing** template code for an **user-defined** type. There is operator+= for std::vector and int is not an user-defined type.

So you can't do what you want (even if it may technically works) it is not legal.

Instead, use `std::transform` or `std::for_each`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> v={{1,2,3,4,5}};
    std::transform(std::begin(v),std::end(v),std::begin(v),[](int x){return x+5;});
    for(auto e :v)
    {
        std::cout<<e<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not think it is a very good idea to hard code the vector value_type into the lambda, especially if you call it very far from the vector declaration. It is much safer to use `decltype(v)::value_type x` instead of `int x`: if you decide to change the vector type this will adapt automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Don't try to change the behaviour of `std::vector`; this is not allowed by the language.

Instead use [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray), which already has support for broadcasting [addition and other operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_arith2).

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify `std::vector`, but technically nothing prevents you to to write your own (global) overload for `operator+=` for vectors and ints:

```
vector<int>& operator+=(vector<int>& v, int x) {
    for (auto a=begin(v); a!=end(v); ++a) {
        *a += x;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/kKXnWS

However, writing overloads for `std` classes is neither straightforward nor the canonical way to solve your problem. I recommend instead using [@ecatmur's solution with `std::valarray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21452304/399317) or [Joachim Pileborg's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452217/increment-all-c-stdvector-values-by-a-constant-value#comment32371738_21452217) of `std::transform` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the great response. However,It looks that valarray could be more efficient than transform... but if I have to convert later to vectors, is it worthy?